# Is there an XML annotation I can use to group class properties together under a common element?

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm trying to group a few class fields together without modifying any code.
I realize I could create a new class which would then group them under that class name, but I don't want to do that.

I have this:

```
<root>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>2</b>
</root>
```

I want this

```
<root>
  <c>
    <a>1</a>
    <b>2</b>
  </c>
</root>
```

But I want that via an annotation, not class restructuring.

I've checked here 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/package-summary.html
but not found anything.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported out-of-box by JAXB but the [EclipseLink-Moxy](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) implementation does support using the `XmlPath` custom annotation. Look at the **Using MOXy to Add a Grouping Element** section in [this tutorial](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/07/xpath-based-mapping.html). Below is a sample for your requirement

```
@XmlRootElement(name="root")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
class MyClass
{
  @XmlPath("c/a")
  String a;

  @XmlPath("c/b")
  String b;
}
```